# How to capture images continuously and control a time based bot at the same time?

Tags: python, multithreading, image-processing, raspberry-pi, python-multithreading

This post is not exactly a  coding problem , but it is more of a code structuring and synchronizing problem . So I have created a bot using Raspberry Pi, which moves in a predefined path as shown in the attached picture . It moves from start->A for 10 seconds , then takes a left and moves for 5 seconds and continues till it reaches the end (Please see the picture for clarity ) . So , I have the code structure for the bot movement in the following way -

```
for directions,time in database:
    while time!=0:
       continue movement in the specified direction .
       time--
```

So , basically it runs a for  loop in Python that finds the direction and Time from a list variable called "database" and moves ahead accordingly .

The second part of the problem is , I have a camera mounted on the bot that captures image continuously and  does a certain task , if an object is detected in front of it . The code structure for the following bot is something like this -

```
for frame in camera.continuous_capture():
   capture image()
   do some calculation() 
   if object in frame()==True:
      do something()
```

The above code is actually a continuous capture method employed in Picamera (Raspberry Pi) . The documentation is - https://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/recipes1.html#capturing-timelapse-sequences

Now , the problem is - I want to integrate this continuous camera capture algorithm with the bot motion . Something like , say , the bot moves from Start-> A , the camera should be active and capture frames continuously , and the bot should move as well . Upon detection of an object (if present) , it should stop the timer for the present path , carry out the necessary action according to the Image processing algorithm and return back to continue its motion in the path it was earlier on .

I have got the Image processing algo working fine , if run separately . And the same goes for Bot movement  . But I am not able to figure out how will I integrate both these functions running side by side , as both of them are utilizing "While" loops , and nesting one inside the other will not give me the desired solution .

So, I wanted to know If "Threading" is what I should do ? Say for ex , the Image processing algo changes a global variable on detecting any change and the Bot movement algo keeps track of the global variable at the same time . On detecting any change to the global variable , the bot algorithm stops and lets the Image processing algo carry out the necessary function . Is this current way to go about it or there is  a better solution to this ?

Pleas help . Please do not downvote this question . I am not trolling and I am also not looking for code help as I can figure that out myself . I just need to know , how to integrate/structure my code .

Thanks !

[Bot path.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg86M.png)